# Asp.net Web Api 2 Identity - How to implement short lived access_tokens that are extended / re-issued

Tags: asp.net-web-api, middleware, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using the `oAuth2` OWIN middleware that comes with the `Web Api 2` project.

Rather than issue tokens that expire after 14 days, I would like to issue, let's say, 20 minute tokens and extend the expiry time another 20 mins if an API Request comes in with an access token that is going to expire in < 10 mins.

Whether a new `access_token` is issued or the expiry time is somehow is extended I don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the refresh token approach for that - I have written a walkthrough here:
http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/

Comment: If the access token expires I want to prompt the user for their credentials and issue a new token. However when "extending" an access_token that is about to expiring I want this to be seamless. Unless I am misunderstanding you blog post that doesn't cover my use case? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Re-prompting for credentials is always an option. Refresh tokens allow silently renewing a token. So it's up to you.